# Mongoose TypeError when use custom Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my code..

```
 var user_schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    last_name: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: [50, "username  not valid "], },
    password: {
        type: String,
        minlength: [8, "El password is short"],
        validate:{
            validator:function (p) {
                return this.password_confirmation == p
            },

            message: "password incorrect "
        }
    },
    age: { Number, min: [17, "age < 17"], max: [75, "age >  75"] },
    email: { type: String, require: " error email ",match:email_match },
    date_of_birth: Date,
    sex: { type: String, enum: { values: posibles_valores , message:"option no valid" } }
})

user_schema.virtual("password_confirmation").get(function () {
    return this.p_c
}).set(function (password) {
    this.p_c = password
    })

user_schema.virtual("full_name").get(function () {
    return this.name + this.last_name
}).set(function (full_name) {
    var words = full_name.split(" ");
    this.name = words[0];
    this.last_name =words[1]

})
```

Error message in console  is:

***Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:614***

```
throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at array `' + path +
    ^
TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at array `age.min`
```

I don't know that happend and my message is not displaying when it is validating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your `age` property declaration:

```
age: { type: Number, min: [17, "age < 17"], max: [75, "age >  75"] },
```

You were missing the `type` property.

Comment: It's funny how that would have been an error in ES5, but because of the shorthand object literal `{ Number }` transforms to `{ Number: Number }`.